# how to support multi-threaded async locking... possibly distributed locking

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, locking

My question involves protecting a critical resource in a multi-threaded and asynchronous system. It is a web application written in both Asp.Net MVC, WebApi, and also WCF projects hosted in IIS. The critical region is the cache (currently, an in-memory System.Runtime.MemoryCache... but see below, could also be distributed AppFabric / Reddis cache)

**Background Domain**
I work in healthcare where we aggregate patient information - such as a list of their documents (e.g. transcriptions, reports), encounter events (e.g. hospital admission), and labs (e.g. blood tests). We have a PatientChart object that tracks all of this data (e.g. ID of all documents + title, but not the actual contents).

**Example Workflow in our system**

- user selects a patient
- request is made to prefetch all the underlying data
- background threads/tasks are fired off to do the work asynchronously
- individual data is stored in the cache, as is the "PatientChart"
  object

**Sample Code**
How do I protect a critical region, i.e. the PatientChart in cache? Here is a stripped down version of what I have right now, using Semaphores:

```
public class PatientProcessorService 
{
    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 1); 

    // this method called asynchronously via multiple parallel threads, based on a master list of document Ids
    private async Task<Document> GetDocument(string patientId, int documentId)
    {
        Document document = _documentService.Get(patientId, documentId);
        await _cacheService.Set(documentCacheKey, document);

        PatientChart patientChart = null;
        await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            patientChart = await _cacheService.Get(cacheKey) as PatientChart;
            if (patientChart != null)
            {
                // update the patient chart with whatever new data/information we have
                patientChart.Message = "Document + " documentId + " retrieved";
                patientChart.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
                patientChart.Documents.Add(new DocumentMetaInfo() {
                    Id=documentId, 
                    Title=document.Title, 
                    CacheKeyLocation=documentCacheKey});
                await _cacheService.Set(cacheKey, patientChart);                  
            }

        }
        finally {
            _semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
    }
 }
```

**Some Questions**

1) Does the above make sense? Anything glaringly wrong with it?

2) Today, the code above is just a prototype to prove out various things. But, if we plan on rolling out this architecture, we will likely have to move out to a distributed cache (e.g. AppFabric, Redis) as well as introduce durable queues (e.g. MSMQ, RabbitMQ) and windows services (as opposed to background tasks/threads in IIS) in order to provide load balancing and scaleability.

In that scenario, I assume my lock has to be implemented much lower down (as I may have different processes accessing the cache). e.g. If I use AppFabric, would I have to use the GetAndLock, and PutAndUnlock api, PLUS this extension written by Guy Godin to support "block+wait" logic (via exceptions and retries and timeout logic)?

http://codingsolution.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/distributed-lock-with-appfabric-caching/

which I believe mimics Redis' implementation:
https://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/RedisLocks

Updated code might look like this?

```
public class PatientProcessorService 
{
    // this method called asynchronously via multiple parallel threads, based on a master list of document Ids
    private async Task<Document> GetDocument(string patientId, int documentId)
    {
        Document document = _documentService.Get(patientId, documentId);
        myAppFabricCache.Set(documentCacheKey, document);

        PatientChart patientChart = null;
        // e.g. using appfabric DataCache and extension from Guy Godin in above link
        using (myAppFabricCache.AquireLock(cacheKey, timeOut)
        {
            patientChart = myAppFabricCache.Get(cacheKey) as PatientChart;
            if (patientChart != null)
            {
                // update the patient chart with whatever new data/information we have
                patientChart.Message = "Document + " documentId + " retrieved";
                patientChart.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
                patientChart.Documents.Add(new DocumentMetaInfo() {
                    Id=documentId, 
                    Title=document.Title, 
                    CacheKeyLocation=documentCacheKey});
                }
                myAppFabricCache.Set(cacheKey, patientChart); 
            }
        }
    }
```

3) The problem above is that I'm not even sure how to refactor the code to make it cahce implementation agnostic... so suggestions on how to do all of this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading this far!

Comment: What is the lifetime of patientChart. From a highlevel point of view is patientChart a "book of record" for a patient?

Comment: Yes, it is like a book of record. Think of it also to be used in the landing page / dashboard type of view. The lifetime will be up to fine tuning - saved in the cache, e.g. for 15 min, or maybe for a day...

Comment: You talk about durable queues and a distributed cache.  I cant help but think this might be candidate for leveraging NServiceBus as a process manager atop your queueing and utilising SOA to split up domains/contexts.  I would even consider levarging CQRS - especially if you are reading more than you are writing and you are intending to scale your reading aspect.